# A single query to update based on the id

Tags: sql, vb.net

i need to update the table based on the two user.

for eg:

```
update table1 set rating=@rate where User1=@userid / user2=@userid
```

so i need to write a single query which satisfy the condition for both the users
user1 and user2.

if i pass the @userid ,if it matches the user's id it should update user1 record. if the id whcih i pass is user2's id then it should update the user2 rec.

How to check for this condition in a single query.......

any idea????????

Comment: Can you post the underlying table structure? I think we might be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

if user1 and user2 are different fields, then

```
update table1 set rating=@rate where (User1=@userid and User2<>@userid) or (User1<>@userid and user2=@userid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  update table1 set rating=@rate 
  where User1=@userid OR
        user2=@userid
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't totally understand what you're asking - assuming you have a table with two id's, `user1` and `user2`, and you want to update that row when `@userId` matches either of the two, you could use:

```
update table1 
set rating = @rate 
where (user1 = @userid or user2 = @userid)
```

Is that what you're looking for?? Or am I misunderstanding your question? If so: please clarify! Maybe show us your table structure or something to help our understanding.